# Rails thinking_sphinx search for any terms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, thinking-sphinx

I'm curious if there's any way to treat all words in a search phrase as an 'or' statement, with records matching any of the words showing up, and most relevant records at the top.

For example I put

```
Transcript.search 'good times'
```

but only get one record when

```
Transcript.search 'good | times'
```

returns 20 records. I tried adding match_mode too

```
Transcript.search 'good times', :match_mode => :any
```

but this still returns just the one record. I could do a string replace and insert | in all the spaces but I feel like I'm just missing something to make this work. Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: I think your second solution is the correct one. and this is fairly easy to implement like `search_terms.split.join(' | ')`. What version are you using because it matters especially with `match_mode`

Comment: BTW you are not missing anything if you are using >v2. It seems `match_mode` is now always `:extended` meaning you have to use `thinking_sphinx` query syntax thus the `|` operator.  [v3 extended syntax](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#extended-syntax)

Comment: Allright i did the split/join method and it seems to work fine. I'll have to test more with some other modifiers added in there but so far so good. Thanks for the comments! And yeah I'm using TS 3.2.4